# HttpOk: Calling client.newCall(request).execute() exists the program un intentionally

Tags: java, http, okhttp

I am using HttpOK library with Java.
I wrote the following code:

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

...

public class RunFeed implements Runnable {

 private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

 ...

 private Response executeRequest(Request request){

    try {
        final Call call = client.newCall(request);
        Response response = call.execute();
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
        }
        return response;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
 }
}
```

The reason I wrote this kind of dirty code is to try and catch the exception which is being thrown on the **call.execute();** line.

What happens is that when the program is reaching this line, the program exits (somehow successfully), without reaching the return response statement, or without any exceptions thrown and without entering the catch block or reaching the last, yes I know - "filthy" return null statement...

The client and request objects are not null and looks valid to me.

Another point to say is that I am running the code from within a runnable implemented class.

BTW,
when the debugger reaches the **call.execute();** line, and I evaluate the expression I get:

> Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://myurl}

So, it seems that everything is fine.
But right after that, when I press the "step Over" button, it just finishes the execution instead of advancing to **if (!response.isSuccessful())**...

Please advise.

Comment: Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48151562/6751083) answer.

Comment: @MohammadRezaKhahani Thank you for the reference. So, after reading the answer, using execute() on the non-main worker thread of the program, as I actually do, is the correct procedure, right?

Comment: Tried to catch throwables but didn't succeed. I want to add that I am not running on Android but on Windows, and that I create the thread (from which I am using the OkHttp calls from a JUnit test. Does that matter?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were writing an android app. I updated my answer. You shouldn't call API in unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

You run the `executeRequest()` method on another thread instead of the main thread, and `call.execute()` runs on the main thread. So, while you're debugging `call.execute()` have enough time to prepare the response, but when the app is running, it doesn't have that chance, and the `executeRequest()` keep executing on another thread.

I suggest consider using `call.enqueue()` instead of `call.execute()`.

**Update**

If you're trying to test okhttp calls, please consider using the [mockwebserver](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver).